# Creating a front page for case workers

Tags: wordpress, civicase

I am trying to create a web form for our caseworkers to be able to use in WordPress, instead of having to go into CiviCRM, but I don't know how t do it, or where to start.
Something like being able to recreate the CiviCase dashboard would be ideal.
Can anyone help?
This is for a registered charity in the UK that helps bring equality to disabled people with Assistance Dogs, so the easier it is for caseworkers, the easier it is to help our clients.

Comment: Hi Dan, What kind of webform you want to show on front end and what sort of information you would be collecting?

Comment: I would like a basic form where the caseworkers are able to search for a member, then create a case, as well as manage the case, all without having to go to the CiviCRM plugin

Comment: what would be idea is to have access to the case dashboard from a front page

Comment: Why can't you use the CiviCRM interface. Using permissions you could hide all the menus and components that they don't need. Otherwise it seems that you'd need to reinvent a lot of functionality.

Comment: Might be worth looking at some of the case extensions in CiviCRM, we have a few very similar requirements for organisations that uses case and the case extensions have helped greatly reduce the complexity/UI issues. Worth a shot before you get into too much dev. Also try the data processor extension for creating your own llistings etc, excellent extension!

Comment: You may need to hold your breath for Ninja Forms https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/y3zmb7en8f8cff881f643fkcfy